# Pandas Apply Lambda causes TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda

I have this dataframe a sample of it is here:

> [image: Blockquote]

I'm having trouble with this code. I'm getting the below error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/....py", line 12, in <module>
 dfF['CCRYear'] = dfF['Year'].apply(lambda x: 'True' if x['Year'] == x['MaxSS Year'] else 'False')   File "C:\Users\....py", line 3848, in apply
 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)   File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2329, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer   
 File "C:/Users/....py", line 12, in <lambda>
 dfF['CCRYear'] = dfF['Year'].apply(lambda x: 'True' if x['Year'] == x['MaxSS Year'] else 'False')
 TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

The Columns 'Year' and 'MaxSS Year' are both int64 datatypes. So this is my code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def cached_date_parser(s):
    if s in cache:
        return cache[s]
    dt = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%Y%m%d', coerce=True)
    cache[s] = dt
    return dt

dfF = pd.read_csv(r'C:\\Users\\....C_14.csv', parse_dates = [1], header='infer')
dfF['CCRYear'] = dfF['Year'].apply(lambda x: 'True' if x['Year'] == x['MaxSS Year'] else 'False')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are using `apply()` on a single columns and you are indexing that.

See what you doing just print the `x` in your `lambda`

```
df['Year'].apply(lambda x: print(x))
```

It will output below

```
2017
2018
2018
2015
2015
2015
```

Your code is trying to index the integer value `x['Year']`. In this `x` is integer years like 2018, 2019 etc.

Change this to

```
dfF['CCRYear'] = dfF['Year'].apply(lambda x: 'True' if x['Year'] == x['MaxSS Year'] else 'False')
```

this

```
dfF['CCRYear'] = dfF['Year'] == dfF['MaxSS Year']
```

Using [np.where()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where)

```
dfF['CCRYear'] = np.where(dfF['Year'] == dfF['MaxSS Year'], 'True', 'False')
```

Comment: Do you think the np.where method would be a faster computation?